# Android - ACTION_SEND image from bitmap

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to send image to other apps but with this code doesn't work. (Other action as delete file or display it, works)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);  
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bos.toByteArray());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

When I send the "image" from the other apps, these crash

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("image/jpg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Pictures/
 image.jpg"));  // choose your path of the image
startActivity(i);
```

hopefully it will help you

Comment: It will work but I don't want to send an email..just send an image from not a static string

Comment: @user3657513 try this new code it works for me thanks